# SQLPlus piping - output data not visible

Tags: pipe, sqlplus

When I run (remotely via Mac client):

```
echo "select table_name from user_tables" | sqlplus 'myuser/mypass@myhost.com:myport/mysid'
```

I get no data displayed:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Nov 2 15:12:57 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>   2  Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

But I know it works because when I run it in interactive mode (i.e. no piping) I do get data back:

```
SQL> select count(*) from user_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       353
```

I do not have a `login.sql` so I was expecting it to show something, even if it was ugly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, it's a minor issue. Don't forget you must emulate EXACTLY what you would type in the interpreter - including the semicolon:

```
echo "select table_name from user_tables;" | sqlplus 'myuser/mypass@myhost.com:myport/mysid'
```

If you want to add formatting options, do what you would verbatim interactively:

```
echo "set pages 200\n select table_name from user_tables;" | sqlplus 'op_qa_zact/saas_admin@odb-scan.di01.qa.itsonsaas.com:1520/QADB01'
```